# PHP get modified array that matches a certain value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array of arrays like below:

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [uid] => 746
            [lid] => 748
        )

   [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [uid] => 746
            [lid] => 744
        )

   [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [uid] => 749
            [lid] => 743
        )


)
```

What I want is to get the modified array that has uid of say 746. So the result I would expect is:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [uid] => 746
                [lid] => 748
            )

       [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [uid] => 746
                [lid] => 744
            )


    )
```

Is there any quick way to do it rather than loop through each element and save the matching array to the return array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it without inspecting each element. That being said you can use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do this (though it will loop behind the scenes):

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item){
    return $item['uid'] == 746;
});
```

Prior to PHP 5.3.0 you will have to declare a function:

```
function filter746($item){
    return $item['uid'] == 746;
}
$arr = array_filter($arr, 'filter746');
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, mate. Cheers.